# Isomorphism of direct product of quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How do I show that with  $n = p^aq^b$ with $p,q$ distinct primes and $a,b \geq 1$ that $$\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \cong (\mathbb Z/p^a\mathbb Z) \times(\mathbb Z/q^b\mathbb Z)?$$ I am told that Bezout's identity may be helpful but I don't know how and am not sure how I would use it. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Actually, it is easier to see as a Chinese Remainder theorem question. But Bezout's identity is basically the big step in CRT.

Comment: Given that you haven't shown any work yet, I'm surprised this question hasn't been closed yet. What do you need for an isomorphism?